# Secure TextField erases data automatically in ios 6

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios6, uitextfield

every one, 
I have encountered a problem in ios 6 with secure textField. It erases the content automatically when I click on Done button on the keyboard. I have checked the value of the secure textField.
In `textFieldShouldReturn`, the `secureTextField.text` is correct. But in `textFieldDidEndEditing`, the `secureTextField.text` becomes nil.

The same secureTextField works perfectly on ios 5.1. And if I make the secureTextField as a normal textField(not secured), then everything goes well. That's to say, notSecuredTextField.text is correct either in `textFieldShouldReturn` or in `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

Any idea?

Here is the code :

> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField{
>
>   ```
>   if (theTextField == self.textFieldPassword){
>       if ([self.textFieldUserName.text length] != 0){
>           [self loginMe];
>           NSLog(@"should return %@", self.textFieldPassword.text);//The value is correct
>           [self.textFieldPassword resignFirstResponder];
>       }
>   }
>   return YES;
>   ```
>
>   }

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"Did End Editing %@", self.textFieldPassword.text);
    if(textField == _textFieldPassword){
        NSLog(@"in text field did end editing %@", self.textFieldPassword.text); // The value is null
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that calling `resignFirstResponder` will cause the undesired action. So copying the data before calling that method solves this problem. Of course, this doesn't really solve the problem, it is just a solution for hiding the problem.

I have created a new project for iOS 6, and the problem doesn't come up.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I'm using XCode 4.5.2 with storyboards, everything working fine and suddenly my secure text field resets when pressing return. Same setup as you, too, in regards to `textFieldShouldReturn`and `textFieldDidEndEditing`.